# automatically inlined functions across translation units and gcc 4.6

Tags: c++, c, gcc

If I don't declare a function f as inlined.  Just as follows:

A.h:

```
X f(Y y);
```

A.cpp:

```
X f(Y y)
{
    ...
}
```

Then in a different translation unit:

B.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"

Z g(W w)
{
    ...
    ... f(...) ...
    ...
}
```

Then I compile the two translation units A.o and B.o with gcc 4.6, and then link them also through gcc.  (Maybe with -O3 to both steps)

Will gcc consider inlining the function for performance at link time?  Or is it too late?

In a code review someone suggested that I shouldn't declare my functions as inline as the compiler knows better than I do when to inline.  I was always under the impression unless the function is defined in the header than the compiler doesn't have the option to inline it.

(If the answer differs for C mode, C++ mode, or gnu++0x mode please point this out also)

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing? `inline` was just invented for that. It allows you to have the definition of the function in the header file without having "multiple defined symbol" errors. And it works sufficiently well nowadays, compilers have good strategies when to effectively inline a function or not.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Why?  Laziness.  I'd rather that the optimizer figure out when it's best to inline a function, in the same way that it figures out when to put a local variable in a register rather than on the stack.  I think this is an uncontroversial view, and you've missed the point.

Comment: Hm, that is exactly what I said. Give the compiler the chance to do it for you. `inline` doesn't mean any thing else than asking the compiler to do it when it is appropriate. To stay with your example, a local variable is fully visible at the point where the compiler decides to keep it in a register or to spill it. Write clean code, and the compiler will be nice with you. And frankly, why is it more difficult to have the definition of a function in a header file than in a .c? Exactly the same text at a different place?

Comment: @JensGustedt: So now you are suggesting that all functions should be defined in headers and `inline`?  Two problems (1) modifying implementation will cause recompile on interface dependents (and the insueing chain reaction), (2) The inline keyword will clutter every function signature.

Comment: Where did I say "all"? And `inline` is not part of the signature, AFAIK. And thing that you were asking for, link time "inlining" would introduce much more subtle dependencies between code than that.

Comment: @JensGustedt: (1) So now you are suggesting that the programmer manually choose some (not "all") functions to be inline candidates, which runs counter to letting the compiler pick.  (2) Function Specifiers are part of the Function Declaration (C++11 7.1.2).  (3) The dependencies of LTO inlining must necessarily be <= those of compile-time inlining.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The feature is called [Link Time Optimization(LTO)](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization) and is not enabled by default in GCC 4.6

[edit]
With LTO enabled, GCC will save a "GIMPLE" representation of `X f(Y y)` in `A.obj`. This representation is slightly more processed than the usual C++ pre-processing, but not a lot. In particular, it's not translated into assembly yet. As a result, the linker can still inline it.

Comment: Can you please add a brief description on how this works in this specific scenario? I didn't have a clue of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think gcc can create make functions split into different source files as inline. It only works if you declare them in the same source file.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler can choose to inline or not for improving performance. But in this case compiler is helpless i think. there is no way it could inline the function f.

NB: Even if you use the keyword its only a suggestion. the ultimate decision of whether to inline or not is upto the compiler. So there isnt any problem in suggesting to compiler.