# Is this a reasonable hack to inline functions across translation units?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm writing performance-sensitive code that really requires me to force certain function calls to be inlined.

For inline functions that are shared between translation units via a header, one would normally have to put the function definition in the header file. I don't want to do that. Some of these functions operate on complex data structures that should not be exposed in the header.

I've gotten around this by simply #including all the .h and .c files once each into a single .c file, so that there is only one translation unit. (That slows down re-compiles, but not by enough to matter.)

This would be "problem solved," but it eliminates getting an error when a function in one C file calls a function in another C file that is supposed to be private, and I want to get an error in that case. So, I have a separate Makefile entry that does a "normal" build, just to check for this case.

In order to force functions declared inline to play nicely in the "normal" build, I actually define a macro, may_inline, which is used where the inline attribute normally would be. It is defined as empty for a normal build and is defined as "inline" for an optimized build.

This seems like an acceptable solution. The only downside I can see is that I can't have private functions in different .c files that have the same prototype, but so far, that hasn't been much of an issue for me.

Another potential solution is to use [GCC's Link-Time Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767395/automatically-inlined-functions-across-translation-units-and-gcc-4-6), which is supposed to allow inlining across translation units. It's a new feature, though, and I don't trust it to always inline things the way I would want. Furthermore, I can only get it working on trivial problems, not my actual code.

Is this an acceptable hack, or am I doing something incredibly stupid? The fact that I've never seen this done before makes me a bit nervous.

Comment: GCC `-flto` is mature enough (notably in GCC 4.8) to be used for pruduction. You should trust it (in GCC 4.8)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks. Well, then, that's my preferred solution.

To everyone else: I am still *very* interested in any answers to my question, because as I mentioned, I can get -flto to work on toy problems, but not my actual codebase. I'm not sure if I'm going to be able to figure out what the problem is. I may end up opening a separate question for that.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that if your various `.c` files use `static` variables at file scope, you'll end up with undesired and undiagnosed sharing of those variables if they have the same name and type.

Comment: I'm still looking into it, but it appears that I can't use -flto with -std=c99. Removing -std=c99 (which required updating all my for loops) allowed the program to work with -flto; however, some of my code got much slower (that, or my profiling tools broke), which, if I understand correctly, can be "correct" behavior for -flto. Hopefully there will be a positive resolution to this, but it may very well turn out that -flto is not a good option in my situation.

Comment: What do you mean by _should not be **exposed** in the header_? ... exposed to whom? When there is only one translation unit, they are as exposed in a .C file as they are in a .H file.

Comment: @Armali Perhaps the .h files are available to third parties for linking against the library.

Answer (score 0):

Unity build is an absolutely valid approach and has been widely used in industry since forever (see e.g. [this post](http://onqtam.com/programming/2018-07-07-unity-builds/)). Recent versions of Visual Studio even provide [builtin support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/07/02/support-for-unity-jumbo-files-in-visual-studio-2017-15-8-experimental/) for them.

LTO has a downside of not being portable even across compilers for the same platform.